# How do I get a list of all differences in a large project

Tags: git, github, branch

I have two branches in a git repository, it's a large project, lots of files and lots of folders, however theres only probably a couple of hundred files that are different, but I'd like everything different to be outputted into a text file. 
I'm not very good with git but when I run the command git diff branch1..branch2 that runs but doesn't do anything. Doesn't even throw an error. 
I've tried just cloning the repository into 2 directories, then being on the different branches and then using unix diff on those folders but that doesn't really seem to be working either, so I think conceptually I'm not sure I even really know how git branches work.

I've used git diff before to compare a remote file to my local file and that works. But this specific situation is confusing me and googling doesn't seem to be helping much.

EDIT - Got the unix diff to work. must've been off a directory before. Would still like suggestions on git diff'ing though

Comment: are you sure that branches are different? Try this command: git diff --name-status branch1..branch2 to show name of changed files.

Comment: returns nothing. I think it must be that I'm not understanding what cloning a repo does. 
I made a directory, went into dir, cloned repo from github, was on initial branch, checkedout other branch.
I think that maybe, I'm not actually getting that branch though, do I need to pull it?

Comment: Cloning the repository you download all, so I can assume that at this moment your branches are equal. Try some tool like gitk and check it.

Comment: hmmm, well thats confusing. When I download the zip of the branch's from github and then unix diff them i get the differences. There are numerous around 1600 lines, which is what I expect. 
I'm on a Mac. I have gitX installed. Which is showing where all the branches diverged.

Comment: I don't know what to say. At this moment, it seems that in the repo branches are equals. Try "git log --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%Cred%d%Creset - %C(cyan)%an %Creset: %s %Cgreen(%cr)' --decorate --graph --all --abbrev-commit" to have a graphical view of branches in your console.

Comment: Are these two branches present on remote?? If yes then you try using "git diff --name-only origin/branch_name"

Comment: Can you give us a overview of your branches with `git remote show origin`? Maybe your remote name is another then `origin`.

Answer (score 0):

Protip: If you just raise a pull request on one of the branches (request branch 1 to be merged into branch 2), and type in '.diff' after the pull request url on github, you get the entire diff between the two branches as a plain text file. You can look at it and find out the differences.

Protip2: Instead of typing '.diff' at the end of the pull request url on github, typing in '.patch' generates a patch file which you can use to apply-patch if you want the changes on one branch to come into another branch in case you are trying to sync them.